# Determining which pattern matched using Regex.Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a translator, not as any serious project, just for fun and to become a bit more familiar with regular expressions. From the code below I think you can work out where I'm going with this (cheezburger anyone?).

I'm using a dictionary which uses a list of regular expressions as the keys and the dictionary value is a `List<string>` which contains a further list of replacement values. If I'm going to do it this way, in order to work out what the substitute is, I obviously need to know what the key is, how can I work out which pattern triggered the match?

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {                     
            {"(?!e)ight", new List<string>(){"ite"}},
            {"(?!ues)tion", new List<string>(){"shun"}},
            {"(?:god|allah|buddah?|diety)", new List<string>(){"ceiling cat"}},
            ..
        }

        var regex = "(" + String.Join(")|(", dictionary.Keys.ToArray()) + ")";

        foreach (Match metamatch in Regex.Matches(input
           , regex
           , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture))
        {
            substitute = GetRandomReplacement(dictionary[ ????? ]);
            input = input.Replace(metamatch.Value, substitute);
        }
```

Is what I'm attempting possible, or is there a better way to achieve this insanity?

Comment: `(?!ues)tion` this makes no sense, since that's just the same as `tion`. Perhaps you want negative lookbehind? `(?<!ues)tion`? Also, `deity`, not `diety`.

Comment: ...and Buddha, not Buddah... and what is a ceiling cat?

Comment: @Tim: I think it's a reference to the viral marketing campaign that had a cat swinging off a ceiling fan.

Comment: Most of the regular expressions (including those in the question) were taken from the ACME-lolcat perl script which does the same thing. I havent had a chance to see if they all work yet.

As for ceiling cat you better consult the bible on that one .. (www.lolcatbible.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can name each capture group in a regular expression and then query the value of each named group in your match. This should allow you to do what you want.

For example, using the regular expression below,

```
(?<Group1>(?!e))ight
```

you can then extract the group matches from your match result:

```
match.Groups["Group1"].Captures
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got another problem.  Check this out:

```
string s = @"My weight is slight.";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<!e)ight\b");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
  s = s.Replace(m.Value, "ite");
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

output:

```
My weite is slite.
```

`String.Replace` is a global operation, so even though `weight` doesn't match the regex, it gets changed anyway when `slight` is found.  You need to do the match, lookup, and replace at the same time; [`Regex.Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) will let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using named groups like Jeff says is the most robust way.

You can also access the groups by number, as they are expressed in your pattern.

```
(first)|(second)
```

can be accessed with

```
match.Groups[1] // match group 2 -> second
```

Of course if you have more parenthesis which you don't want to include, use the non-capture operator ?:

```
((?:f|F)irst)|((?:s|S)econd)

match.Groups[1].Value // also match group 2 -> second
```